# Mybatis collection with multiple columns

Tags: mybatis

I have a table which has three foreign keys to items. These corresponding objects I want in a list property. I have the following collection mapping

```
<collection property="items" column="{item1Id, item2Id, item3Id}">
    <association property="exampleNestedItem" column="{id, ###itemId###}" select="com.example.mapper.getItem" />
</collection>
```

I need the current value at ###itemId###. How can I reference the columns "item1Id", "item2Id" and "item3Id" for this Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a very easy solution. In my case I know that there will always be 3 elements in that list. So I added a setter for each element in the model class like this

```
public void setElement1(Element element) {
   elements.add(element);
}
...
```

and I added an association for each element

```
<association property="element1" column="element1Id" select="com.example.mapper.getItemWithId"/>    
...
```

It will for sure not scale for many elements, but for my case it fits!